# Trying to understand Girsanov's theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

This is Girsanov's theorem from wikipedia:

Let $\left\{W_{t}\right\}$ be a Wiener process on the Wiener probability space $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P\}$. Let $\left\{X_{t}\right\}$ be a measurable process adapted to the natural filtration of the Wiener process $\left\{\mathcal{F}_{t}^{W}\right\}$ with $X_{0}=0$.
Define the Doléans-Dade exponential $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ of $X$ with respect to $W$
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}=\exp \left(X_{t}-\frac{1}{2}[X]_{t}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $[X]_{t}$ is the quadratic variation of $X_{t} .$ If $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ is a strictly positive martingale, a probability measure $Q$ can be defined on $\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}\}$ such that we have Radon-Nikodym derivative
\begin{equation*}
\left.\frac{d Q}{d P}\right|_{\mathcal{F}_{t}}=\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}
\end{equation*}
Then for each $t$ the measure $Q$ restricted to the unaugmented sigma fields $\mathcal{F}_{t}^{W}$ is equivalent to $P$ restricted to $\mathcal{F}_{t}^{W}$. Furthermore, if $Y$ is a local martingale under $P$, then the process
\begin{equation*}
\tilde{Y}_{t}=Y_{t}-[Y, X]_{t}
\end{equation*}
is a Q local martingale on the filtered probability space $\left\{\Omega, \mathcal{F}, Q,\left\{\mathcal{F}_{t}^{W}\right\}\right\}$.

Here are my questions:

1. $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ must be a martingale with regard to which filtration ?
2. How can a Radon-Nikodym derivative be equal to $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ ? A Radon-Nikodym derivative is a deterministic function but $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ is random (unless $Q$ is a random measure, which is not stated).
3. Why do we need $\mathcal{E}(X)_{t}$ to be a strictly positive martingale to be able to define $Q$ ?
4. Where can I get a proof of the theorem formulated in this way ? I seem to find a lot of different versions in textbooks, none like the above.

Comment: I have the feeling that specific questions like this are better suited for MO

Comment: 1- The stochastic exponential should be a martingale w.r.t the filtration generated by $X_t$.  2- if you have a measure space $(X,\Sigma)$, and a measure $\nu$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative (w.r.t another measure $\mu$) is a function with non-negative values defined on $X$, in this case your measure space is $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, so the R.N derivative is a random variable!

Comment: 3-otherwise P and Q are not mutually absolutely continuous 4- Protter's book has a Girsanov theorem expressed in this form but unless mistaken